# Reuse linear mapping that provides the solution to least squares problem using LAPACK

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, lapack, quadratic-programming

LAPACK.gglse allows me to solve

```
min x^T Q x
s.t. A x = y
```

(in my present use case, $Q$ is symmetric positive definite)
without having to think about the numerical stability, computational efficiency, and bug potential of my own attempts of wiring up the solution

```
x^* := L y
where L := Q^{-1} A^T (A Q^{-1} A^T)^{-1}
```

Does LAPACK also allow me to efficiently solve multiple such systems with the same `Q` and `A`, without recomputing the core $O(N^3)$ algorithm, i.e., does it allow me to store the data required to compute matrix vector products with `L`? (I don't care whether that be by directly providing me with the entries of `L` or by providing a decomposition-like array.)

Comment: Is $Q$ symmetric?  positive definite?

Comment: @BrianBorchers both

Comment: Are you sure `gglse` solves that problem? In the docs the objective function has a slightly different form.

Comment: @Federico You are right, but I can store the  Cholesky decomposition easily in my case (although maybe doing that already is a bad idea for numerical stability of solving this problem?)

Answer (score 2):

I think the equations might not match (`min x^T Q x` vs `min |c-Q x|_2`), but I still think i understood the core question; can one reuse the expensive factorization when calling `gglse` repeatedly.

Some LAPACK-functions takes pre-factorized inputs partly for this very reason, but it does not seem to be the case with `gglse`, and it will recompute the `ggrqf` factorization each time.

Browsing the code in the netlib reference implementation for `dgglse`, it's quite well documented regarding the steps it factorization + solver steps it performs, excluding some boilerplate the reference LAPACK from netlib.org 3.10.1 version does:

```
 *     Compute the GRQ factorization of matrices B and A:
 *
 *            B*Q**T = (  0  T12 ) P   Z**T*A*Q**T = ( R11 R12 ) N-P
 *                        N-P  P                     (  0  R22 ) M+P-N
 *                                                      N-P  P
 *
 *     where T12 and R11 are upper triangular, and Q and Z are
 *     orthogonal.
 *
       CALL dggrqf( p, m, n, b, ldb, work, a, lda, work( p+1 ),
      $             work( p+mn+1 ), lwork-p-mn, info )
   lopt = work( p+mn+1 )
 *
 *     Update c = Z**T *c = ( c1 ) N-P
 *                          ( c2 ) M+P-N
 *
   CALL dormqr( 'Left', 'Transpose', m, 1, mn, a, lda, work( p+1 ),
  $             c, max( 1, m ), work( p+mn+1 ), lwork-p-mn, info )
       lopt = max( lopt, int( work( p+mn+1 ) ) )
 *
 *     Solve T12*x2 = d for x2
 *
       IF( p.GT.0 ) THEN
          CALL dtrtrs( 'Upper', 'No transpose', 'Non-unit', p, 1,
      $                b( 1, n-p+1 ), ldb, d, p, info )
 *
      IF( info.GT.0 ) THEN
         info = 1
         RETURN
      END IF
 *
 *        Put the solution in X
 *
      CALL dcopy( p, d, 1, x( n-p+1 ), 1 )
 *
 *        Update c1
 *
      CALL dgemv( 'No transpose', n-p, p, -one, a( 1, n-p+1 ), lda,
  $               d, 1, one, c, 1 )
       END IF
 *
 *     Solve R11*x1 = c1 for x1
 *
       IF( n.GT.p ) THEN
          CALL dtrtrs( 'Upper', 'No transpose', 'Non-unit', n-p, 1,
      $                a, lda, c, n-p, info )
 *
      IF( info.GT.0 ) THEN
         info = 2
         RETURN
      END IF
 *
 *        Put the solutions in X
 *
      CALL dcopy( n-p, c, 1, x, 1 )
   END IF
 *
 *     Compute the residual vector:
 *
   IF( m.LT.n ) THEN
      nr = m + p - n
      IF( nr.GT.0 )
  $      CALL dgemv( 'No transpose', nr, n-m, -one, a( n-p+1, m+1 ),
      $                  lda, d( nr+1 ), 1, one, c( n-p+1 ), 1 )
   ELSE
      nr = p
   END IF
   IF( nr.GT.0 ) THEN
      CALL dtrmv( 'Upper', 'No transpose', 'Non unit', nr,
  $               a( n-p+1, n-p+1 ), lda, d, 1 )
          CALL daxpy( nr, -one, d, 1, c( n-p+1 ), 1 )
       END IF
 *
 *     Backward transformation x = Q**T*x
 *
       CALL dormrq( 'Left', 'Transpose', n, 1, p, b, ldb, work( 1 ), x,
      $             n, work( p+mn+1 ), lwork-p-mn, info )
       work( 1 ) = p + mn + max( lopt, int( work( p+mn+1 ) ) )
```

where you would only need to call `*ggrqf` only once.
You may even be able to simplify away some steps with $c=0$ for your particular case.

Though of course, bug potential is far from zero here.